Typescript: Cannot access 'createResettable' before initialization
I have a couple simple components using Zustand and NextJS.
For some reason I am getting  the following error: "Cannot access 'createResettable' before initialization". I am defining the function and importing it correctly? Not sure why I am getting this?
./quoteStore.ts
import { createResettable } from "../_hooks/hooks"; // verified import is correct
import { type Customer } from "./types";

type QuoteStore = {
  id: string | null;
  date: string | null;
  customer: Customer | null;
  subTotal: string;
  tax: string;
  total: string;
  taxRate: number;

  //Setters
  setCustomer: (customer: Customer | null) => void;
  setQuoteDefaults: (
    input: Pick<
      QuoteStore,
      "id" | "date" | "customer" | "subTotal" | "tax" | "total" | "taxRate"
    >,
  ) => void;
  setTotals: (subTotal: string, tax: string, total: string) => void;
};

export const useQuoteStore = createResettable<QuoteStore>((set) => ({ // This is where the error happens
  id: null,
  date: null,
  customer: null,
  subTotal: "0",
  tax: "0",
  total: "0",
  taxRate: 0,

  setCustomer: (customer) => set({ customer }),
  setQuoteDefaults: (input) => set(input),
  setTotals: (subTotal, tax, total) => set({ subTotal, tax, total }),
}));

._hooks/hooks.ts
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { vanillaApi } from "@/trpc/react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import Decimal from "decimal.js";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { create } from "zustand";
import type { StateCreator } from "zustand";
import { useQuoteStore } from "../\_stores/quoteStore";

export const createResettable = \<T\>(stateCreator: StateCreator\<T\>) =\> {
const store = create(stateCreator);

const initialState = store.getState();
storeResetFns.add(() =\> {
store.setState(initialState, true);
});
return store;
};

Originally I was exporting createResettable as create, I thought perhaps the types were clashing with Zustand. I renamed it to createResettable. The issue persists.

There’s a circular reference with import { useQuoteStore } from "../\_stores/quoteStore"; in hooks.ts. It doesn’t seem to be used there. Maybe it can be deleted?

@TimMoore It's not really a problem. There's no problem with circular references in import statements. The problem is in the Promises they generate. If you try to get something from them when they're not fulfilled then this error will be thrown. Se the answer I made below for more details.

Copy of my comments from SG. quoteStore.ts can't import and use createResettable from hooks.ts if hooks.ts is trying to import and use useQuoteStore from quoteStore.ts. One or both of these functions needs to be declared/used in a third file that doesn't create a circular dependency between quoteStore.ts and hooks.ts. It looks like useQuoteStore isn't used in hooks.ts at all though, so that import can likely just be deleted. You can't use useQuoteStore outside a React component or custom hook anyway. I'm voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

NOTE that you can make circular references in imports... But you must be aware because it will not work in every case. You can't use (at top level) something from the other that (at top level) is using something from the file that imported it (which is pretty much unknowable in most cases). It's needed to wait for the files to fully load and fill the references in the interpreter context.
That being said, I didn't find any fault within the exposed code.
But I have this very intriguing feeling that hints to me that there's something imported at hooks.ts that is using something either from quoteStore.ts, hooks.ts or both. It can also be in quoteStore.ts though, maybe in _stores/types.
Here's an example of working circular importing:
module1.mjs
import m2 from './module2.mjs';
// or
// import { m2 } from './module2.mjs';

// m2 is a Promise until fulfilled then is the default
// export from `module2.mjs`.

// Does not produce error.
const m1 = { m2 };

export default m1;

// TEST:

// Does not produce error as it awaits for m2 to be fulfilled.
console.log(m2())
// Outputs: { m2: [Function: m2] }
// The output above is the default `{ m2 }` above
// which is a circular reference.

// Does not produce error as it awaits for m2 to be fulfilled.
console.log(m2().m2);
// Outputs: [Function: m2]

// This file does use m2 from the top level.

module2.mjs
import m1 from './module1.mjs';

// m1 is a Promise until fulfilled then is the default
// export from `module1.mjs`.

// Does not produce error.
const m2 = () => m1;

export default m2;

// This file does not use m1 from the top level.

But you'll incur in problems if you try this at module2.mjs:
import m1 from './module1.mjs';

// m1 is a Promise until fulfilled then is the default
// export from `module1.mjs`.

// Does not produce error.
export const m2 = () => m1;
// m1 is not at top level above.

// This produces an Error because m1 was not fulfilled.
// export const m3 = m1.m2;
export const m3 = m1.m2;
// m1 is at top level above.

export default m2;

// This file does use the m1 from the top level.

NOTE that the top level is asynchronous. That's what makes the interpreter wait for m2 to be fulfilled in module1.mjs.
PS.: In CommonJS the top level is the top Window object. But each ESModule is its own top level.
